# Install EPSON TM-T88V printer with CUPS in Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, printing, cups, pi-3b+

I am trying to install the EPSON TM-T88V printer with CUPS in Raspberry pi 3, but I can not make prints, the status of the printer says "inactive". I tried the PPD file "tm-ba-thermal-rastertotmt.ppd" but it does not work.

Anyone knows how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still trying to install the necessary packages then this script may help:

```
#!/bin/sh
#install Epson printer TM-88 / TM-20
sudo mkdir /tmp/install
cd /tmp/install
sudo wget -O /install/master.zip 'https://github.com/plinth666/epsonsimplecups/archive/master.zip'
sudo unzip master.zip
cd epsonsimplecups-master
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2-dev
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then:

1. In a browser, go to http://localhost:631
2. Click on the **Administration** Tab,
3. Click **Add Printer**,
4. Click **Unknown** radio button and **Continue**
5. Enter a **Name**, i.e. Epson
6. Click **Continue**
7. Under **Make** select **Epson**
8. Under **Model** select **Epson TX-T20**
9. Click **Add Printer**
10. Set the **Media** size
11. Click **Set Default Options**
12. Under the **Maintenance** pop up, select **Print Test Page**

Answer (score 0):

I tried the package from plinth666 but the raster wasn't quite proper. I used then a bunch of free code from Epson, a PPD file from another printer and modify them to produce this new package: https://github.com/groolot/epson-tm-t88v-driver

Better rasterization, cash drawer and buzzer, all is operational.

Hope that could help someone like I was: in pain.